# DateChooser format changes on different machine

Tags: java, datechooser

I have used DateChooser jar in my project. On linux(Ubuntu) when I tested the date displayed is in the format `dd/MM/yy` and when I tested the same project on Windows machine the date displayed was in the format `MM/dd/yy`. Following is code snippet:

```
        SimpleDateFormat chooserDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss");

        dteKCActDate = new DateChooserCombo();
        dteKCActDate.setBounds(new Rectangle(11, 23, 164, 21));
        dteKCActDate.setFieldFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        dteKCActDate.setNavigateFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        dteKCActDate.setFormat(3);
        dteKCActDate.setCurrentNavigateIndex(1);
        dteKCActDate.setNothingAllowed(false);
        dteKCActDate.getSelectedDate();         

        dteKCActDate.addSelectionChangedListener(new datechooser.events.SelectionChangedListener() {
            public void onSelectionChange(datechooser.events.SelectionChangedEvent evt) {
                MultyDateChooseModel iObj=((MultyDateChooseModel)evt.getSource());                                               
                    iObj.commit();            
            }
        });
```

My question is why the difference in date format being displayed when I switch to different machine.

Answer (score 0):

SimpleDateFormat(String pattern) uses the computer's default date format symbols for the default locale. If you want it to be the same on every machine, try setting a fixed locale with SimpleDateFormat(String pattern, Locale locale).